# How to make make a dynamically created button click event use data of a row of a database table in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, button

In C# windows form. Assuming I have 10 rows in my table. All has name and age. How do I dynamically create a button that uses all the data of a row in the button's click.event?

Ex. First button uses name1 and age1 values
Second button uses name2 and age2 values... And so on...

Thank you for your response!

EDIT:
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

```
protected void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button button = sender as Button;
    // identify which button was clicked and perform.  
necessary actions
//sql query to retrieve data from database
Txtbox.text=//row n Name
Txtbox2.text=//row n Age

//where n is the row number
}
```

Wherein each created button has a different button_click with also different txtbox.text= VALUE

Im sorry if I cannot precisely explain it.

Comment: There is zero informations about what framework or method to display such a button you use.

Comment: what have you tried so far? How are you retrieving the data from the database?

Comment: Please add more explanation to your specific problem, e.g.. what is the framework you are using? , how you receive data...

Comment: Sorry if the information's not enough. I did add some codes tho. Please try to check it. Thanks.